# Does meta_query working with value paramater higher then 999?

Tags: meta-query, meta-value

I am trying to get posts by price using `query_post()` function. Price must be in range between two values. This I made using `meta_query`. But when I cant get posts when right value higher then 999 in `'value' => array(0, 999)`. When it is lower all fine. Where I am wrong?

I have products with price value = 100. So maybe during query execution 1000 interpreted as 100? Also I have products with prices = 240. When I am setting 'value' => array(0, 2300) I cant get products with prices 240.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'        => 'product',
    'product-category' => get_query_var('product-category'),
    'orderby'          => 'wpcf-product-price',
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'       => array(
        array(
        'key'      => 'wpcf-product-price',
        'value'    => array(0, 1000),
        'compare'  => 'BETWEEN',
        ),
    ),
);
query_posts( $args );
```

Here are dump of $wp_query:

```
  ...["meta_query"]=>
  object(WP_Meta_Query)#4450 (2) {
    ["queries"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(18) "wpcf-product-price"
        ["value"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          int(0)
          [1]=>
          int(10000)
        }
        ["compare"]=>
        string(7) "BETWEEN"
      }
    }
    ["relation"]=>
    string(3) "AND"
  }
  ["date_query"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["request"]=>
  string(565) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (3,6,7,8) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'wpcf-product-price' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) BETWEEN '0' AND '10000') ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 10"
  ["posts"]=>
  array(1) ...{
```

As you can see value in `BETWEEN` is 10000 but I get 1 product: `...["posts"]=> array(1) {...`. When value is 9999 then I have all products: `...["posts"]=> array(5) {...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution by using `type` parameter in `meta_query`, set it to `numeric`. By default it is `char` and 1000 interpreted as string.

```
'meta_query'       => array(
    array(
    'key'      => 'wpcf-product-price',
    'value'    => array(0, 1000),
    'type'     => 'numeric',
    'compare'  => 'BETWEEN',
    ),
),
```

Comment: Did you mean "As by default..." instead of "So by default..."?

Comment: "So" removed :)